# EVENTTARGET Problem determing sender

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I am trying to figure out what button was clicked, this code works just fine in IE, but if I Chrome, Firefox, or Safari it doesnt do anything. When using firebug in firefox, I looked at the Form Details, and it shows that EVENTTARGET has no value its just blank. How can I get this to work on FF, Chrome, and Safari?

Method:

```
       Control postbackControlInstance = null;

        string postbackControlName = page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
        if (postbackControlName != null && postbackControlName != string.Empty)
        {
            postbackControlInstance = page.FindControl(postbackControlName);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < page.Request.Form.Keys.Count; i++)
            {
                postbackControlInstance = page.FindControl(page.Request.Form.Keys[i]);
                if (postbackControlInstance is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)
                {
                    return postbackControlInstance;
                }
            }
        }
        if (postbackControlInstance == null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < page.Request.Form.Count; i++)
            {
                if ((page.Request.Form.Keys[i].EndsWith(".x")) || (page.Request.Form.Keys[i].EndsWith(".y")))
                {
                    postbackControlInstance = page.FindControl(page.Request.Form.Keys[i].Substring(0, page.Request.Form.Keys[i].Length - 2));
                    return postbackControlInstance;
                }
            }
        }
        return postbackControlInstance;
```

Code Calling Method:

```
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                Control cause = GetPostBackControl(Page);
                string statecause = cause.ID;
                if (statecause == "buttonName1")
                {
                    search(statecause);
                }
                else if (statecause == "buttonNAME2")
                {
                    resetfields();
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to determine what control that caused the postback is to override `protected` `Page.RaisePostBackEvent` method. This method is used by ASP.NET infrastucture to notify the server control that caused the postback that it should handle an incoming postback event:

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(
        IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, 
        string eventArgument
    )
    {
        // here is the control that caused the postback
        var postBackControl = sourceControl;

        base.RaisePostBackEvent(sourceControl, eventArgument);
    }
}
```

The code you provided should work for scenarious when the client-side `__doPostBack` function is rendered to the page (e.g. if you use the only one button like `<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="submit" UseSubmitBehavior="true" />` it won't be rendered) only.

If even in the case when the `__doPostBack` function is rendered, but `__EVENTTARGET` parameter is empty it means that the default behaviour of the `__doPostBack` function is violated by custom/incompatible javascript code in the most cases. In this case even ASP.NET infrastructure will be unable to handle post back events properly.