# __EVENTTARGET is empty on postback of button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button on aspx page

```
<asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="sc-ButtonHeightWidth" ID="btnFirstSave" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

I am trying to get the event target and event source in code behind to do some validation based on it. I tried with below code.

```
string ctrlname = page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
string ctrlname = Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"];
string ctrlname = Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
```

But all the above are giving me empty values. How to get the control which caused postback everytime. Am i doing anyting wrong above?

FYI : I already tried the solution mentioned in this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704500/eventtarget-problem-determing-sender). But its only returning button text for me. I want the buttonID.

Comment: try with `<asp:Button  runat="server" usesubmitbehavior="false" ...`

Comment: @Damith Thanks for the comment. Is there any problem setting this property to "false"? I see some answers below by Vignesh Kumar and Suraj Singh, That is also a working solution. But your comment is easier compare to them. I went through "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx". But i din't get any answer to "Is it causes any behavioral change of button?"

Comment: @Naveen when we do `usesubmitbehavior="false"` the `type` of `input` changes from `submit` to `button`

Comment: This change has an impact : the form is submittable with javascript disabled with a submit type. But with a button type, the form will be no more submittable without javascript. (Maybe it is not an issue in your case, of course.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have set usesubmitbehavior to false as of now. A good solution given by Damith above in the comment. As of now its working fine for me without any problem. To know about the property [Read this LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 17):

Asp button renders as `input` with type `submit` this method will not fill`_EVENTTARGET`
controls using `"__doPostBack"` method to cause postback will add values to `_EVENTTARGET` 
so your button id is missing from `_EVENTTARGET` you can iterate through all the controls in page to check which control caused postback.

Try this to capture Your control -[Here](http://geekswithblogs.net/mahesh/archive/2006/06/27/83264.aspx)

```
private string getPostBackControlName()
        {
            Control control = null;
            //first we will check the "__EVENTTARGET" because if post back made by       the controls
            //which used "_doPostBack" function also available in Request.Form collection.
            string ctrlname = Page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
            if (ctrlname != null && ctrlname != String.Empty)
            {
                control = Page.FindControl(ctrlname);
            }
            // if __EVENTTARGET is null, the control is a button type and we need to
            // iterate over the form collection to find it
            else
            {
                string ctrlStr = String.Empty;
                Control c = null;
                foreach (string ctl in Page.Request.Form)
                {
                    //handle ImageButton they having an additional "quasi-property" in their Id which identifies
                    //mouse x and y coordinates
                    if (ctl.EndsWith(".x") || ctl.EndsWith(".y"))
                    {
                        ctrlStr = ctl.Substring(0, ctl.Length - 2);
                        c = Page.FindControl(ctrlStr);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        c = Page.FindControl(ctl);
                    }
                    if (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button ||
                             c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton)
                    {
                        control = c;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return control.ID;

        }
```

Comment: Thanks Suraj for the answer. I have some doubts which i added as comment under my question. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: @Naveen  `UseSubmitBehavior` property specifies if the Button control uses the browser's built-in submit function or the ASP.NET postback mechanism. So i do not think using `Damien` solution is going to cause any issues.See when button renders as `<input`  with submit type it does not uses Asp.Net mechanism of postback, so it do not fills up `_Eventtarget` by changing submit behavior you are just making sure it uses `Asp.Net` mechanism `("_doPostback")`and i think it will be better for your current situation than mine solution .

Comment: @ Suraj Thank you. Even i thought so. But you also gave a good solution, up-vote for that.

Comment: I think the answer [linked here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3509755/2912011) is a little bit more comprehensive. Still a good answer though.

Comment: @David Rogers Thanks for the appreciation I will try to make this answer more efficient soon.

Answer (score 4):

Just add UseSubmitBehavior="False" to your button.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="sc-ButtonHeightWidth" ID="btnFirstSave" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the ID of the post back control.
/// 
/// See: http://geekswithblogs.net/mahesh/archive/2006/06/27/83264.aspx
/// </summary>
/// <param name = "page">The page.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string GetPostBackControlId(this Page page)
{
    if (!page.IsPostBack)
        return string.Empty;

    Control control = null;
    // first we will check the "__EVENTTARGET" because if post back made by the controls
    // which used "_doPostBack" function also available in Request.Form collection.
    string controlName = page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(controlName))
    {
        control = page.FindControl(controlName);
    }
    else
    {
        // if __EVENTTARGET is null, the control is a button type and we need to
        // iterate over the form collection to find it

        // ReSharper disable TooWideLocalVariableScope
        string controlId;
        Control foundControl;
        // ReSharper restore TooWideLocalVariableScope

        foreach (string ctl in page.Request.Form)
        {
            // handle ImageButton they having an additional "quasi-property" 
            // in their Id which identifies mouse x and y coordinates
            if (ctl.EndsWith(".x") || ctl.EndsWith(".y"))
            {
                controlId = ctl.Substring(0, ctl.Length - 2);
                foundControl = page.FindControl(controlId);
            }
            else
            {
                foundControl = page.FindControl(ctl);
            }

            if (!(foundControl is Button || foundControl is ImageButton)) continue;

            control = foundControl;
            break;
        }
    }

    return control == null ? String.Empty : control.ID;
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175513/on-postback-how-can-i-check-which-control-cause-postback-in-page-init-event)

Answer (score 0):

My solution.I add OnClick event like this on my client side

`function btnClickSuper(s, e)
{
    __doPostBack(s.name, '');
}`

here `s` is object presented my button in DevExpress, where property `name` contains, as part of, an Id of elment. so ,on server side,  I can get Id of button sent postback. Price is server OnClick enevnt isn't fired.