# In an ASP.NET web form, how to determine what causes a Page_Load()

Tags: asp.net, pageload

I want to implement a finite state machine (FSM) inside a typical ASP.NET web form.  I would like the FSM "engine" to be automatically invoked each time a Page_Load() event happens - which is easy enough - but I also want the engine to receive information about which event caused the Page_Load() to occur.  The difficulty is that in an ASP.NET web form, a user-controlled event, such as a button click, can cause the page to reload, but the event handler for the button click itself does not get invoked until after the Page_Load() event fires.  As far as I can tell, the Page_Load() handler itself does not contain any information about what user event caused the page to reload.  I would prefer not to have to explicitly invoke the FSM engine from within each event-handler method.  Is there any way to accomplish this? -- to have Page_Load(), or some other stage in the page life-cycle, "know" what particular user action caused the page to reload?

Comment: It looks like the solution is here: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838022/eventtarget-is-empty-on-postback-of-button-click"

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Web forms will store it in a parameter in the `Request` object. You can get it like this:

```
// Find the control name
string nameOfControlWhichCausedPostback = page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
```

Then find the control with that name:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(nameOfControlWhichCausedPostback ))
{
    var ctrl = page.FindControl(nameOfControlWhichCausedPostback );
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised to see that __EVENTTARGET is not in the list of Page.Request.Params.  The button click is definitely invoking the Page_Load(), but that item is not there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838022/eventtarget-is-empty-on-postback-of-button-click